# C Language - This is probably a seg fault error, but i'm not sure?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Good morning everyone. I'm trying to run the following code but it simply doesn't work:

```
void test(u_long *vector, int nLines) {
    int i, j;
    u_long *bkpVector=(u_long *)malloc(0);

    for (i=0; i<=100000; i+=10000) {
        printf("vector of size: i=%d\n\n", i);
        if (i>0) {
            if (bkpVector!=NULL) {
                printf("NOT NULL\n");
                bkpVector=(u_long *)realloc(bkpVector, i*sizeof(u_long));
            }
            else {
                printf("NULL POINTER\n");
                bkpVector= (u_long *)malloc(i*sizeof(u_long));
            }
        }

        //printf("Vector: ");

        for (j=0; j<i; j++) {
            printf("null: %d ", bkpVector==NULL);
            bkpVector[j]=vector[j];
        }
        //printf("\nz\n\n");

        TestBubbleSort(2, bkpVector, i);

        for (j=0; j<i; j++)
            bkpVector[j]=vector[j];
        TestInsertionSort(2, bkpVector, i);

        for (j=0; j<i; j++)
            bkpVector[j]=vector[j];
        TestMergeSort(2, bkpVector, i);

        printf("\n");
    }

    free(bkpVector);
}
```

It usually crashes at the line `bkpVector[j]=vector[j];`. Do you guys have any suggestion on what could be wrong? Could anyone please help? I'm new to *SO*, so forgive me any mistakes. Thank you very much!

Comment: Most likely, `j` is outside the bounds of the arrays. Check that with your debugger. Also, don't cast `malloc` on the RHS. It's unnecessary and even occasionally harmful. Also, note an `int` can be as small as 32767, consider using a `long` for better portability,.

Comment: @Bathsheba `i` is the number of elements in the array just allocated with `realloc()`, and `j < i` in the `for` loop. So how can it be outside the bounds?

Comment: What is the value of `i` and `j` when that line creashes? Are you sure the input `vector` is big enough? Why doesn't the function use `nLines`? Is that the number of elements in `vector`?

Comment: Please note that `malloc(0)` invokes implementation-defined behavior and is therefore not a good idea to use. To achieve what you want, it is better to initialize all pointers to NULL and set them to NULL in case they are freed. Then you may safely use realloc if a given pointer is not NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of things that ARE wrong in your code.

Firstly, it implicitly assumes that `vector` has (at least) `100000` elements.  If that is not true, the two loops of the form

```
for(j=0; j<i; j++)
        bkpVector[j]=vector[j];
```

will exhibit undefined behaviour for any value of `i` exceeding the actual number of elements in `vector`.

Second, `malloc()` and `realloc()` can fail - and return a `NULL` pointer if they do.   Your code simply uses the returned value like an array, without checking if the allocations succeeded.   If `NULL` has been returned, doing that causes undefined behaviour.

Lastly, it is a really bad idea in C - despite the fact that it is advocated in some circles - to convert (aka typecast) the return value from `malloc()` or `realloc()`.   Needing to do so (e.g. to avoid diagnostics from a C compiler) typically means you have forgotten to `#include <stdlib.h>` and, in that case, forcing the code to compile by doing a type conversion results in undefined behaviour.    [Note - a type conversion is also required if your C compiler is actually a C++ compiler, but using `malloc()` and `realloc()` in C++ is also inadvisable for various reasons].

A common symptom of undefined behaviour is a program crash.

Although, not strictly incorrect, it is usually considered a poor idea to `malloc(0)`.   In your usage, initialising `bkpVector` to `NULL` would suffice.

Comment: Yeah i tried initializing bkpVector to NULL but it still didn't work :( Do you have any other suggestion? Thanks for replying!

Comment: Initialising to `NULL` will not fix your problems.    You need to fix the three other problems I mentioned as well - they are unaffected if the pointer is initialised to `NULL`.